# How to append no results to SeaORM Mocking interface?

Tags: rust, sea-orm

I want to test a block of code that `selects` before `insert`. If the `select` find the element by id then we don't insert. If we get `None` then we can insert.

```
if TheEntity::find_by_id(id).one(&db).await?.is_some() {
    //Do not insert and do other stuff...
}else{
    //Insert the new entity.
}
```

How can I instruct `MockDatabase` to return a `no results` result?

```
MockDatabase::new(DatabaseBackend::Sqlite)
   .append_query_results([
       //Here instead of return this Model I want to return None.
       vec![my_entity::Model{id: "TheId".to_string()}]
   ]);
```

Comment: Not familiar with SeaORM or its mocking, but does `vec![]` not work?

Comment: Nop. When empty vector we get a runtime error. Stream empty.

Comment: Adding to the last comment. Thats expected since we are defining the results. And using and empty vector we are saying: no select statements are being called.

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but I meant `.append_query_results([ vec![] ])` by my comment. That would mean one select statement is expected and would return no results, right?

Comment: You are completely right. I had to cast but it works. It was a really dumb question in the end....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an Empty vector and is working now...

```
MockDatabase::new(DatabaseBackend::Sqlite)
   .append_query_results([vec![] as Vec<model:MyEntity>]);
```